# casting to (id<protocol>) to guarantee a property is there

Tags: objective-c, protocols

if i have a number of classes with something like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myString;
```

and want to access that property in a object that is one of these classes (but don't know which so it is type id), i obviously get "request for member 'myString' in something not a structure or union" error.

so if each of these classes conforms to :

```
@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

@required

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myString;

@end
```

then i cast like this to get the property:

```
(id<myProtocol>)anObject.myString
```

why doesn't this work? i still get the same error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this case I prefer the messages-sending notation over the dot-notation, as it shows clearly, when the cast will happen:

These lines are equal:

```
[(id<MyProtocol>)anObject myString]
((id<MyProtocol>)anObject).myString
```

And these are:

```
(id<MyProtocol>)[anObject myString]
(id<MyProtocol>)anObject.myString
```

Answer (score 6):

ignore this.. turns out just to need more brackets:

```
((id<myProtocol>)anObject).myString
```

Comment: in other words, it's a precedence issue -- dot has higher precedence than cast in C